# Strange BUG in my ListView (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a simple **Navigation Drawer** which includes `EditText` and `ListView`.

It looks like this:

http://s7.postimg.org/7uzzvf723/SSS_default.png

Everything works great but I found out that when I fast scroll down listview just at the beginning of the app (when I have already opened Navigation Drawer), it **sometimes** shows me this:

http://s11.postimg.org/pmlktkmer/SSS.png

I really do not know what causes this problem and of course I do not know how to fix that.
Is it posible that this problem causes `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in my XML file ?

Any advices for me ?

Thank you!

Comment: First, you will want to provide some more code so we can see what your doing. Second, if you think animateLayoutChanges may be the issue, try disabling it and testing.

Comment: @KalelWade Thank you for your willingness. I will try to upload my code to GitHub. I disabled animateLayoutChanges but as I said sometimes it works but sometimes it shows me "bug".

Comment: @lubosmj have you tried this on a stock Android device? You look like you're running a custom rom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 40 minutes of **hard working** I came to my solution. I do not know why but maybe it is not very good to use android predefined animations. Bugs are now gone, I hope...

My XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#F09609"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >  <!-- I meant this. -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search_action_hint"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" 
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true" /> <!-- When I deleted this one, no bugs. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Big thank to @KalelWade who came with this solution!

Thank you!